# Trimmed mean on computed (avg) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am taking the average number of minutes between two date fields - of xreports in the last 5 days - this works well:

```
select avg(datediff(minute, findDateTime, reportClosedDateTime)) as avd from xreports 
where findDateTime > dateadd(day, -5, getdate())
```

However, there are many outliers skewing this average, so I'd like to take the interquartile range - ie lose the top and bottom 25%.

I found this [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/computing-the-trimmed-mean-in-sql).

This explains how to do it on a real column, but I can't get it to work with Avg() of the difference between 2 columns - this is the best i can do:

```
declare @pp float 
set @pp = .25 

select avg(datediff(minute, findDateTime, reportClosedDateTime)) as avd 
from xreports xr
where findDateTime > dateadd(day, -5, getdate())
and 
    (select count(*) from xReports xr1
        where xr1.finddatetime <= xr.finddatetime) >= 
            (select @pp*count(*) from xReports) 
    and 
    (select count(*) from xReports xr2
        where xr2.avd >= xr.avd) >= 
            (select @pp*count(*) from xReports)
```

However, the column "avd" isn't recognised.

How can I do this?

thx.

Comment: Column `avd` isn't recognised because you can't refer to an alias within the same query level. Put it within a subquery. Anyways, there is space for optimization for this query, but just giving you a rod.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about doing that? How would you suggest optimizing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use window functions. Here `row_number` and `count` does the job of accounting the correct percentage for a row within a supplied resultset.

```
select avg(datediff(minute, findDateTime, reportClosedDateTime)) as avd
from (
  select
    *, 
    row_number() over (order by datediff(minute, findDateTime, reportClosedDateTime)) * 1.0 / count(*) over () as pn
  from xreports
  where findDateTime > dateadd(day, -5, getdate())
  ) t
where pn > 0.25 and pn < 0.75
```

You could use other window functions, but I find this clearer for non-experienced users.

I'm including `* 1.0` to make the division return fractional digits for correct calculation of percentages.

Answer (score 0):

That is so not the way to do this in SQL Server 2016.  Here is one method:

```
select avg(datediff(minute, xr.findDateTime, xr.reportClosedDateTime))
from (select xr.*,
             row_number() over (order by datediff(minute, xr.findDateTime, xr.reportClosedDateTime)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from xreports xr
     ) xr
where seqnum >= cnt * 0.25 and
      seqnum <= cnt * 0.75;
```

Other window functions such as `ntile()` and `percentile()` can also be used.  This explicit counting approach seems closest to what is in your question.

Comment: And what was the problem you had with this query?  There is no obvious syntax error.

Comment: It just returned null?!

Comment: @niico . . . Are you sure the `WHERE` clause is correct?  This would only return `NULL` if `cnt` were 1.